# Does NGiNX Ingress Controller of Azure Kubernetes support multiple protocol

Tags: azure, msmq, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am looking for a one stop solution to support multiple protocol request to my backend, such as MSMQ, HTTP, MQTT. Can I achieve this using Azure Kubernetes NGiNX ingress controller?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/announcing-nginx-ingress-controller-for-kubernetes-release-1-4-0/#tcp-udp). Maybe it's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx ingress only supports HTTP, TCP and UDP:

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/#exposing-tcp-and-udp-services

so if you treat those as tcp or udp (whatever they use, I'm not familiar with those) you can achieve that.